# Scripting an 'empty' password in /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, slackware, authorized-keys

I've written a script to add CVS and SVN users on a Linux server (Slackware 14.0).  This script creates the user if necessary, and either copies the user's SSH key from an existing shell account or generates a new SSH key.

Just to be clear, the accounts are specifically for SVN or CVS.  So the entry in `/home/${username}/.ssh/authorized_keys` begins with (using CVS as an example):

```
command="/usr/bin/cvs server",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ....etc...etc...etc...
```

Actual shell access will never be allowed for these users - they are purely there to provide access to our source repositories via SSH.

My problem is that when I add a new user, they get an empty password in `/etc/shadow` by default.  It looks like:

```
paddycvs:!:15679:0:99999:7:::
```

If I leave the shadow file as is (with the `!`), SSH authentication fails.  To enable SSH, I must first run `passwd` for the new user and enter something.

I have two issues with doing that.  First, it requires user input which I can't allow in this script.  Second, it potentially allows the user to login at the physical terminal (if they have physical access, which they might, and know the secret password -- okay, so that's unlikely).

The way I normally prevent users from logging in is to set their shell to `/bin/false`, but if I do that then SSH doesn't work either!

Does anyone have a suggestion for scripting this?  Should I simply use `sed` or something and replace the relevant line in the shadow file with a preset encrypted secret password string?  Or is there a better way?

Cheers =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid problems with locking, or messing up your shadow file, you could conceivably use

```
echo username:some_string | chpasswd
```

More specifically: you could actually use the `*` in the password field by doing this:

```
echo "username:*" | chpasswd -e
```

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I was looking for.  Much cleaner than my hack with `sed`, and obviously more robust.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried

```
passwd -d username
```

it deletes the password entry of the particular user from the `/etc/shadow file`.  Basically making the particular user login as empty password.

It can only be enforced as root or sudo user.

Answer (score 4):

And yet another solution which doesn't involve a pipe is the following (also found in the shadow, resp. shadow-utils package):

```
usermod -p '*' username
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I played around a bit more and I found that if I turn the password into `*` in `/etc/shadow`, it allows SSH but disables password logins on the TTY.  So I'll add this as an answer to my own question.

This has been added to my script after the `useradd` call:

```
cp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow.backup
sed -e "s/^\(${username}:\)[^:]*:/\1*:/" /etc/shadow.backup > /etc/shadow
```

It replaces a specific user's shadow password entry with a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of OpenSSH check /etc/shadow to see if the account is disabled.  A disabled account has an !, so changing that to an * will solve the problem.